# counting leaf nodes in a tree

Tags: algorithm, tree

Assume we have a tree where every node has pre-decided set of outgoing nodes. Is it possible to come up with a fast way/optimizations to count the number of leaf nodes given a level value? Would be great if someone could suggest any ideas/links/resources to do the same.

Comment: Do you mean that each node has exactly `d` children?

Comment: @SalvadorDali not necessarily

Comment: then there is no easy way to count it (by easy I mean without looking through the whole tree), because the code is actually easy.

Comment: @SalvadorDali haha yes, i mean faster than O(N) in practice. You know, with some optimizations..

Answer (score 0):

No. you'd still have to traverse the entire tree. There's no way of predicting the precise structure - or approximating it - from only the number of childnodes of each node of the tree.

Apart from that: just keep a counter and update it on each insertion. Far simpler and wouldn't change time-complexity of any operation, except for counting leaves, which would be reduced to `O(1)`.

Comment: Could you provide a simple pseudocode on how we could calculate the 'number' of leaf nodes in O(1) time?

Comment: @N.M. As i already wrote in the answer: just use a counter for leaves. I don't think this needs any code to explain. And the code would be nearly a complete implementation of a tree

Answer (score 0):

This can actually get pretty tough thing. As it varies of what is the programming language, what is the input data structure, is the tree binary or general tree (arbitrary number of children), size of the tree.

The most general idea is to run a DFS or BFS, starting from the root, to get every node level and then make a list of sets where each set contains the nodes of a single level. The set can be any structure, standard list is fine.

Let's say you are working in C++ which is good, if not the best practical choice if you need performance (even better than C).

Let's say we have a general tree and the input structure is adjacency list as you mentioned.

```
//nodes are numbered from zero to N-1
vector<vector<int>> adjList;
```

Then you run either a BFS or DFS, either will do for a tree, keeping a level for each node. The level for a next node is the level of it's parent plus one.

Once you discover the level, you put the node in like this.

```
vector<vector<int>> nodesPartitionedByLevels(nodeCount);
//run bfs here
//inside it you call
nodesPartitionedByLevels[level].push_back(node)
```

That's about it.

Then when you have the levels, you iterate all the nodes on that level and you check the adjaceny list if it contans any nodes.

basically you call `adjList[node].empty()`. If true than that is a leaf node.